# "react-native run-android" command is not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, command, web-development-server

I'm new to react native and trying to set up the environment before I start coding. Whenever I try to run the command: 'react-native run-android', it throws an error:
Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`. [image: error Image]

I'm following the documentation but still getting the error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you should add JAVA_HOME to windows environment variables, try to install Java SE Development Kit (JDK) with Chocolatey or download from https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/

if doesn't work:

Right click My Computer and select Properties. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1, Apply and close Properties, now it works

Answer (score 0):

you can use `AndroidStudio` for open emulator , after open emulator you can use `react-native run-android` , after app installed you can use `react-native start` for more time.

you most install JDK for run java, and set `JAVA_HOME` in `Environment Variables`.

Set the JAVA_HOME Variable
To set the JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME variable:

1.Locate your Java installation directory

If you didn't change the path during installation, it'll be something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

You can also type where java at the command prompt.

2.Do one of the following:

Windows 7 – Right click My Computer and select Properties > Advanced

Windows 8 – Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings

Windows 10 – Search for Environment Variables then select Edit the system environment variables

3.Click the Environment Variables button.

4.Under System Variables, click New.

5.In the Variable Name field, enter either:

> JAVA_HOME if you installed the JDK (Java Development Kit)
> or
> JRE_HOME if you installed the JRE (Java Runtime Environment)

6.In the Variable Value field, enter your JDK or JRE installation path .

for more see this link [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)